# Generate EC KeyPair from OpenSSL at the same time

Tags: openssl

I would like to create an EC private an public key and have them in one file. I can create a private key with:

```
openssl ecparam -genkey -name prime256v1 -noout -out ec256-key-pair.pem
```

But like this, the file contains only the private key. Is there a parameter, that openSSL creates both keys at the same time?

I would like to have a file which looks like this:

```
-----BEGIN EC PARAMETERS-----
BgUrgQQACg==
-----END EC PARAMETERS-----
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
MHQCAQEEIKMPbg+xGGkig+N+lLzCJ9mJ019yqicZezlbF3IeuQkUoAcGBSuBBAAK
oUQDQgAEor2P+NfmQDuS7mcSVGp6b4AiMXkwlKayJcOLMFjovue1ZsUjMIbw53P3
AF5+G6N0arUq+9tT87a+TTRwxiXYqA==
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAE///n/cRdxm49shZtjnrQxnemfJgF
A8UVjNyXtShULmgOJOQh7E9yZfomLkFj0FVkd1M9g7hfL+DO3Utl61kJcg==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Comment: openssl ec -in ec256-key-pair.pem -pubout -text

Comment: I would like to have both keys in the same file, if this is possible.

Comment: yes possible, using a shell script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But like this, the file contains only the private key.

The file `ec256-key-pair.pem` actually includes both the private and the public parts of the key pair. You can verify that by printing its contents using the `openssl ec` command:

```
$ openssl ec -in ec256-key-pair.pem -noout -text
read EC key
Private-Key: (256 bit)
priv:
    a3:0f:6e:0f:b1:18:69:22:83:e3:7e:94:bc:c2:27:
    d9:89:d3:5f:72:aa:27:19:7b:39:5b:17:72:1e:b9:
    09:14
pub:
    04:a2:bd:8f:f8:d7:e6:40:3b:92:ee:67:12:54:6a:
    7a:6f:80:22:31:79:30:94:a6:b2:25:c3:8b:30:58:
    e8:be:e7:b5:66:c5:23:30:86:f0:e7:73:f7:00:5e:
    7e:1b:a3:74:6a:b5:2a:fb:db:53:f3:b6:be:4d:34:
    70:c6:25:d8:a8
ASN1 OID: secp256k1
```

In fact, you can see that it also contains the curve identifier.

> I would like to have a file which looks like this:

If you still want this in spite of the information above, you can extract the three different parts with the `openssl ec` command. Use option `-param_out` for the parameters, no option for the private key (which in fact includes the public part) and `-pubout` for the public part only.

```
$ openssl ec -in ec256-key-pair.pem -param_out > result.txt
$ openssl ec -in ec256-key-pair.pem >> result.txt
$ openssl ec -in ec256-key-pair.pem -pubout >> result.txt
```

With this, `result.txt` will contain what you asked for. For everything in a one-liner, like you requested:

```
$ KEY_PEM=$(openssl ecparam -genkey -name prime256v1 -noout) && for OPTION in -param_out "" -pubout; do openssl ec -in <(echo "${KEY_PEM}") ${OPTION}; done > result.txt
```

(Assuming you are using `bash` as your shell)

Comment: That works perfectly. Would it also be possible to do everything in one go without using an intermediate file? I actually call this from a C++ program as an external process and would like to capture the output. It would be great if I just have to call one process where I can capture the private key and the public key. Or is there a C++ library which I could use for this. Sorry about the stupid questions, but I never used openSSL before.

Comment: I added a one-liner but have not verified that it works if you invoke this shell command from your application. In stead of using the `openssl` tool, you could use its `crypto` library to do this programmatically from your C++ application. You can learn how to do that by reading [the OpenSSL EC wiki page](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Elliptic_Curve_Cryptography) and/or inspecting [the `ec` app's source code](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_1_1f/apps/ec.c#L257).

Comment: That works fine. But know I played around with the OpenSSL lib. I can create a keypair now. I posted the code in my original question.

Comment: Good, that seems like a better approach. Since the nature of your new problem is different, you should pose it as a new question though.

Comment: Ok. I posted the new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61173864/generat-ec-keypair-with-openssl-library